# How i can import an entire js file with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to import my file functions.js in my file index.js and use variables and functions are in functions.js.

For ex:
I have an variable x in my file functions.js. I import functions.js like "import './functions.js';" in my index.js. The path is correct for sure(they are in the same directory).  But when i try to use x, i have this next error ->
"index.js:01 Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined"

functions.js
`export var x = 0;`

index.js

```
import './functions.js';
console.log(x);
```

Thanks ! :)

Comment: If you're using ES Modules, you can import all exports like this `import * as name from "module-name";`. You can't omit the import name. In your example `x` is not defined, even if it's defined in the `functions.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of modules is to get away from this business of sharing everything in a single scope (the global scope, by default in non-module scripts). If you want to do that, don't use modules, use non-module scripts.

Modules are defined in terms of

- What they provide (`export`)
- What they expect (`import`)

In general, you're best off making those relationships explicit:

```
import { x } from "./fonctions.js";
// ...use `x`...
```

That assumes `x` is a *named export*:

```
export const x = /*...*/;
// or
export function x() {
    // ...
};
// etc.
```

The closest thing to an "import everything from X" construct in JavaScript modules is a *module namespace object* import, which looks like this:

```
import * as fonctions from "./fonctions.js";
```

You'd then use `fonctions.x` to refer to `x`. **But**, `x` still has to be exported from `fonctions.js` (as above). Anything declared in a module that **isn't** explicitly exported is private to that module, and so it doesn't show up on the module namespace object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

So i'm already trying to use import * as f from './functions.js'. But that's create somes problems. Like i want to modify and use some variables from functions.js and i got this error: 'TypeError: Cannot set property map of # which has only a getter'.

So i use x.value for pass this error but that's init other problems. (With my map from leaflet...)

Comment: @YannisHaismannPlugimmo - Imports (regardless of how you do the import) are *read-only views* of the exported item. If you have `export let answer = 42;` in `a.js`, and `import { answer } from "./a.js";` in `b.js`, in code in `b.js` you can't assign to `answer`, you get the error you mentioned. That's by design. (Code in the source module `a.js` can modify `answer`, and `b.js` code would see those modifications, but they can't directly cause them.) If `a.js` wants to allow other modules to modify `answer`, it has to provide an exported function that does that. You may find that...

Comment: ...you want to export an object from `fonctions.js`: `export const stuff = { x: 42, /*...*/ };`. Then you can import the object (`import { stuff } from "./fonctions.js";`) and you can assign to `stuff.x` (since that's just a normal boring object property).